# How to check if one array of objects value with another array of objects value, if found then hide something?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to check one array of objects value exists in another array of objects value (Means if both values matches then i am disabling the table row). So for that how do i check both array of objects values. See my below two array objects.

```
const array1 = [
{
id: "8a8080877134b405017134c1adb3004f",
name: "AWS API1"
},
{
id: "8a8080b6720900d301720935a7120000",
name: "AWS API3"
},
{
id: "8a80808271773317017177848a5106d1",
name: "AZURE API1"
}
];

const array2 = [
{
apiId: "8a8080877134b405017134c1adb4444f",
apiName: "AWS API2"
},
{
apiId: "ass34dgdfgfdgfdg35435ERF",
apiName: "AZURE API1"
},
{
apiId: "dfdfdaggfdgdfg4324564",
apiName: "AWS API1"
}
];
```

From the above 2 array of objects, i want to check if the array2.apiName matches with array1.name then i want to disable table row. So how to achieve it?

See the below code.

```
const r = array1.filter((elem) => !array2.find(({ apiName }) => elem.name === apiName));
console.log(r);
```

Comment: You want an array of matching elements or just a boolean value if there is any match?

Comment: Hey Rana, If there is any match of the value exists in the array1.name when compared with array2.apiName. I mean if both arrays objects values like AWS API1 === AWS API1 some thing like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use array [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method on both the arrays and introduce a new property `disable` into the first array. And set `disable` property to `true` if it's `name` is present in second array's `apiName` property.

And in the template use the `disable` property to disable/enable the rows.

But beware, the `some` method will iterate each element of the first array with all the elements of the second array. So it could be a relatively heavy process for considerably large arrays.

```js
var array1 = [
  { id: "8a8080877134b405017134c1adb3004f", name: "AWS API1" },
  { id: "8a8080b6720900d301720935a7120000", name: "AWS API3" },
  { id: "8a80808271773317017177848a5106d1", name: "AZURE API1" }
];

var array2 = [
  { apiId: "8a8080877134b405017134c1adb4444f", apiName: "AWS API2" },
  { apiId: "ass34dgdfgfdgfdg35435ERF", apiName: "AZURE API1" },
  { apiId: "dfdfdaggfdgdfg4324564", apiName: "AWS API1" }
];

array1.some(a1 => {
  array2.some(a2 => {
    if (a1.name === a2.apiName) {
      a1.disable = true;
    } else {
      if (a1.disable !== true) {
        a1.disable = false;
      }
    }
  })
});

console.log(array1);
```